# how to load postgres boolean values into sql server using ssis package

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have the following situation:

- Source Connection: Postgres Server
- Source table : Emp
- Source column: status*(data type is Boolean and values like true/false)*
- Target Connection: Sql Server
- Target table : emp
- Target column: Status *(data type is Boolean)*

I created an ODBC connection for Postgres server and I used ADO.Net source, the `Status` column datatype is showing `DT_NText` for Status column (actual Postgres side its boolean)

While loading data from postgres database table to sql server using ssis package 
side I am getting error.

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Derived Column" (47) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Derived Column Input" (48). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I am unable to load  Postgres boolean values into sql server using ssis package.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: The error message is thrown by a Derived Column Transformation, can you show what you are trying to do with it?? what is the derived column expression?